# Parse string and loop angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, parsing

I take some string in format like this: "Something for example $takeThis $takeThisAlso". So what I want is to parse string and get list of all strings that have $ ($xxx). Something like this:

```
foreach($xxx in list) {
   var field = xxx; // here I want field to have value takeThis
   // do something with this field
}
```

So what is best practice for this in Angular. To use some old plain javascript or maybe we have something from angular.

Comment: Are you looking for [$interpolate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate)?

Comment: Hm..if i can use that for my case why not. I will need to look what this $interpolate is. I am  quite new in angular :D

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want the filter function on angular, which can also accept a predicate

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Comment: hm...not sure. How can I use filter to take all that starts with $?